# How to hide a input element of a webpage using onclick() function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to hide specific section of display i.e, onclick of a button. How can i achieve it with pure javascript. here is a piece of my code.

`<input type="radio" name="fx" value="YES" onClick="other();hide();"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="fx" value="NO" checked> No`

On selecting 'YES' in the radio button i want to hide/disable this input field:

`<INPUT TYPE="number"  id="ctc" NAME="fctc" value=0 required/>`

Comment: You want to hide all content within...what?

Comment: sorry my question wasn't clear, I have edited it. I only want a section of it to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research i found the solution to hide the input field

```
function hide() {
var newHTML="<input type='hidden' name='ctc' value='0'>";
document.getElementById("ctc").innerHTML = newHTML;

 }

<input type="radio" name="fx" value="YES" onClick="hide();"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="fx" value="NO" checked> No
<p id="ctc"> <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="ctc"  value=0 required/></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener using javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", hideElm);
```

and in hideElm function you can hide the element

```
function hideElm() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must, define a function to hide the element or assign a style that makes in invisible, like so https://jsfiddle.net/wfu9k0ck/

Otherwise take a look at event listeners. you assign a listener to an element, like

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonsId").addEventListener("click", functionToRemove);
```

when the button is clicked the eventListener fires the event, in this case `functionToRemove`